# How to conduct test for normality before conducting an ANOVA?

Tags: anova, normality-assumption

Our research plans to use one-way ANOVA, but upon encountering the assumptions of it, we had to conduct the test for normality and homoscedasticity. We're going to compare 3 populations(Grade 10,11,12 students) with 2 dependent variables(parental perfectionism, career indecision) to be done separately.
I have decided upon using the Anderson-Darling Test, but my problem is, will I be testing each population for each dependent variable, or combine the three populations for each dependent variable and perform the Anderson-Darling test?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you expect "parental perfectionism" and "career indecision" to be distributed normally in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption for a general linear model is that the data are *marginally* normal.  That is, that the distributions of errors from the model are normally distributed. So, you want to take the residuals from the model, and assess those for normality.

I recommend against using a test to assess normality in the way you are suggesting.  The problem is that these tests are sensitive to sample size and will find a significant deviation from normal for a large data set even if the deviation is small.

You are better off using visual methods.  Your eyes and brain are a better judge.  You can use a quantile-quantile plot or a histogram of residuals that you can compare to a normal distribution.

Comment: A bigger problem is not having a power of 1.0 so missing non-normality when n is small.  It is better practice to just use nonparametric tests if you are not somewhat certain of normal residuals.  Checking the data to find out how to model the data can distort statistical inference.

Comment: So visual methods of a combination of 3 populations for each dependent variable? Sorry but our school only taught us until Pearson Correlation Coefficient, all of these were my part of my personal research.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Use Kruskal-Wallis Test instead?(the non-parametric equivalent of ANOVA)

Comment: Our sample size is n=20, still too sensitive to non-normality?

Comment: Yes,  combo of samples for each DV, but you want to look at the residuals from the analysis, not the original data.  You should also take to heart @Frank Harrell 's comment.  Especially if your dependent variables aren't really continuous variables, a nonparametric test may be more appropriate (Kruskal-Wallis perhaps).  For what you're doing if you're not real comfortable looking at the assumptions of anova, probably K-W with a Dunn test post-hoc will be easy, familiar to readers, and will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I'm still dealing with the controversial issue as to whether likert's scale gives ordinal or interval data.

Comment: But note that nonparametric methods perform excellently under normality too.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, could you point me to any papers or resources that talk about how checking the data to find out how to model the data can distort statistical inference? This seems like a common practice but I have been wondering about this.

Comment: I don't have my finger on it but not hard to simulate.  Clearest example in when researcher bias causes interpretation of test of normality to be influenced by significance of the first p-value computed.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Kruskal-Wallis Test has an asymptotic efficiency of 95.5% compared to ANOVA, similarly for Mann Whitney U post hoc test compared to t-test. Which post hoc test do you guys suggest to use then?

Comment: I assume you mean multiple comparison procedures.  For this I use those tests' generalization: the proportional odds ordinal logistic model.  With that model you can form any contrasts you need on the log odds cumulative probability scale.